# R Split String By Delimiter in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a file with several lines. For example

```
A               B       C    
awer.ttp.net    Code    554
abcd.ttp.net    Code    747
asdf.ttp.net    Part    554
xyz.ttp.net     Part    747
```

I want to use R to split just column A of the table and I want a new column added to the table D, with values awe, abcd, asdf, and xyz.  Would prefer this to be done using dplyr.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want us to write code for you, this is the wrong site :) Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic about questions that might be asked here.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `mutate` and `gsub`:

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% mutate(D=gsub("\\..*","",A))

              A    B   C    D
   awer.ttp.net Code 554 awer
   abcd.ttp.net Code 747 abcd
   asdf.ttp.net Part 554 asdf
    xyz.ttp.net Part 747  xyz
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am however looking for something a bit more generally applicable. Like I want this to work even if the last part isn't ttp.net for example lets say its yyp.net or ttp.abc.org, etc

Comment: If you want to keep only what is before the first dot, then you can do `gsub("\\..*","",A)`. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 11):

We can use `tidyverse` for this

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   separate(A, into = 'D', extra = 'drop', remove = FALSE) %>% 
   select(LETTERS[1:4])
#             A    B   C    D
#1 awer.ttp.net Code 554 awer
#2 abcd.ttp.net Code 747 abcd
#3 asdf.ttp.net Part 554 asdf
#4  xyz.ttp.net Part 747  xyz
```

Comment: I get the error LETTERS[1:4]: must resolve to integer column positions, not character. Also, it may not just be the first 4 letters. I need everything until the first . regardless of the number of letters.

Comment: @AdamSmith  I am using `dplyr_0.7.0`  Can you test it without the `select` step

Answer (score 1):

First I create the dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- 
   data.frame(
        A=c("awer.ttp.net","abcd.ttp.net", "asdf.ttp.net", "xyz.ttp.net"),
        B=c("Code", "Code", "Part", "Part"),
        C=c(554,747,554,747), 
        stringsAsFactors = F
   )
```

Then mutate the new column this way:

```
data %>% 
    mutate(
        D = strsplit(A, "[.]") %>% 
            as.data.frame() %>% 
            t %>% 
            data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F) %>% 
            pull(1)
   )
```