# R - Splitting strings in a column on a character and keeping specific results

Tags: r, plyr, gsub

This link is 90% of the way to solving what I want do figure out: [R Split String By Delimiter in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981338/r-split-string-by-delimiter-in-a-column)

Here's the example input:

```
A               B       C    
awer.ttp.net    Code    554
abcd.ttp.net    Code    747
asdf.ttp.net    Part    554
xyz.ttp.net     Part    747
```

And the desired result:

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% mutate(D=gsub("\\..*","",A))

A    B   C    D
awer.ttp.net Code 554 awer
abcd.ttp.net Code 747 abcd
asdf.ttp.net Part 554 asdf
xyz.ttp.net Part 747  xyz
```

But this only gives you the string before the first dot. What if you want the following?

```
A    B   C    D
awer.ttp.net Code 554 ttp
abcd.ttp.net Code 747 ttp
asdf.ttp.net Part 554 ttp
xyz.ttp.net Part 747  ttp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can capture as a group.  Match one or more characters that are not a `.` (`[^.]+`) from the beginning (`^`) of string followed by a `.` followed by another set of characters that are not a dot captured as a group (`([^.]+)`) followed by other character and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(D= sub("^[^.]+\\.([^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", A))
#             A    B   C   D
#1 awer.ttp.net Code 554 ttp
#2 abcd.ttp.net Code 747 ttp
#3 asdf.ttp.net Part 554 ttp
#4  xyz.ttp.net Part 747 ttp
```

Or using `extract`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   extract(A, into = 'D', "^[^.]+\\.([^.]+).*", remove = FALSE)
```

Note that we don't need the `dplyr` for this

```
df1$D <- sub("^[^.]+\\.([^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", df1$A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strsplit` function for this, and wrap it in a function that returns the part you want.

Make your dataframe

```
temp <- "A               B       C
awer.ttp.net    Code    554
abcd.ttp.net    Code    747
asdf.ttp.net    Part    554
xyz.ttp.net     Part    747
"
df <- read.table(textConnection(temp), header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE )
```

We want use the `strsplit` function, which splits a string at a given pattern, and returns a list containing a vector with the different strings. For instance:

```
strsplit("A-B-C-D", "-")
#[[1]]
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

Wrap this into a function that returns a specified part

```
mystrsplit <- function(x, pattern, part=2){
  return(strsplit(x, pattern)[[1]][part])
}
# Vectorize it so that it can handle vector arguments of x
mystrsplit <- Vectorize(mystrsplit, vectorize.args = "x")
```

Use our `mystrsplit` function in mutate:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(D=mystrsplit(A, '\\.', 2))

#             A    B   C   D
#1 awer.ttp.net Code 554 ttp
#2 abcd.ttp.net Code 747 ttp
#3 asdf.ttp.net Part 554 ttp
#4  xyz.ttp.net Part 747 ttp
```